# Nuxt3: SSR on direct navigation, client-side fetching on in-app navigation

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, metadata, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3

So we have a Nuxt3 application with a page `/thing` which uses data from endpoint  `/api/thing` to render content but *also* for generating dynamic metadata during SSR (for SEO and social cards).

Now, `pages/thing.vue` uses `useFetch` which fetches the data during SSR (good or dynamic metadata, bad for UX since blocks navigation).

Ideally, we'd have it use `useFetch` if the client is navigating to `/thing` directly (e.g. by typing it in their browser and pressing enter) but use non-navigation-blocking `useLazyFetch` and show a loading page on the front-end when the client is navigating within our app.

How can that be achieved?